# Motors settings

Tags: arduino-mega, motor, stepper

I'm trying to build my own 3D printer with [a guide](http://www.instructables.com/id/Complete-newbie-step-by-step-3D-printer-with-all-p/?ALLSTEPS) but I've got a problem with two of my CD/DVD motors: I don't know which settings to set in Marlin (`configuration.h`) because I can't find any datasheet for them.

So, I tried to set some values by my own, but I'm a little lost. That's why I'm asking for some help!

I'm using an **Arduino Mega 2560** (with Marlin firmware), a **RAMPS 1.4** and **x4 A4988 modules**.

- The 1st motor has "**7810200082AC**" engraved on front and "**D5X08VF1D**" printed on the back.
- The 2nd motor has "**05Z20P2B**" and "**092KPL201ACP**" printed on the back.

If I wasn't clear or some information is missing, please tell me!

[image: Motors]

Comment: I have played with a few of same looking steppers, burned one up as the one I had was a 3V one, ended up using a 9110 controller for it. So be aware of it getting extremely hot, you might need lower voltage.

Comment: Unless you are planning to make a printer with a build area no larger than the length of those screws, those tiny floppy drive motors are probably unsuitable.  Anyway, this is not meaningfully an "Arduino" question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact setup, but when it comes to steppers, you just need to know a few things:

- Meter the coils to get an impression, how much current you can induce.
- Limit the current on your driver as low as possible (<= 0.25 A possible?)
- Test
- Heighten the current, if the motor doesn't turn or stalls

Your motors are quite small, so I would assume, they run with less than 0.25 A at 12 V or 0.125 A at 24 V and so on.

If you limit the current, nothing can go wrong at all. Check the heat from time to time and make sure, your drivers lowers the current, whenever the given axis stands still.

When it comes to to resolution, I would not recommend to use more than 1/4 steps, which would result in 4*48/round steps on a standard stepper and provides very good resolution plus smooth motor action.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.

So I, set the **Vref at 0.2V** (multimeter says 0.199) to get 0.25A with a **Rs at 0.1Ohm** (0.25A * 8 * 0.1Ohm = 0.2V) and I put a jumper to get 1/4 steps.

Now, I don't know which values to set in Marlin for: **DEFAULT_AXIS_STEPS_PER_UNIT**, **DEFAULT_MAX_FEEDRATE**, **DEFAULT_MAX_ACCELERATION**.

I tried some values and the motor moves smoother than before with driver's settings but I don't know how to find exact values without a datasheet.

Comment: Huh .2V seems really less, I thought about .25A@12V which would result in 3 watts. .25@.2V is just 0,05 watts. Not enough to turn your motor, I guess. When it comes to Marlin: You need to know, how much your spindle moves during one turn (lets say: 1cm)  and how much steps your stepper does (substeps included) per round (lets say: 48*4). So you have 48*4 Steps per cm. Feedrate is very hard to guess. Try 150 on Z and 4 times more on X and Y. Accelleration is very dependend of your driver. Experiement.

Comment: You need to lower/raise the current on the A4988 modules with this tiny screw. Check the manual.